# Pass-through a safe resource URL from component @Input to DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, xss

I have a component that has an URL (of type string) as `@Input`. It passes that URL through to a DOM element in its template. This will cause an error:

`unsafe value used in a resource URL context`

To bypass this error I can use `DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` in the component. However, now any URL (of type string) that is passed into the `@Input` will bypass security. I'd like consumers of my component to also get an error, because those consumers are responsible for passing in a valid and safe URL.

I have tried to use `SafeResourceURL` as the type of my `@Input`, but that results in the same behavior as passing in a string.

An example of my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-svg",
  template: `
    <object
      type="image/svg+xml"
      [data]="url"
      >
    </object>
  `
})
export class MySvgComponent {
  @Input() url: string;
}
```

I want that the above error appears on the consumer-side and that the consumer needs to use `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` when the URL is from a variable source:

```
<my-svg [url]="thisIsAnUnsafeUrl"></my-svg>
```